# Achieve this using animation. Sliding the pictures to there respected place

Tags: ios, swift, animation

[Link to Present output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snk3t.gif)

I have achieved the output in the video using the below code:

```
class GigMainViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var imgViewCenter: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var imgViewLeft: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var imgViewRight: AnimatableImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var lblPageNum: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var viewLeftMost: UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var viewLeftCenter: UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var viewRightMost: UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var viewRightCenter: UIView?

//MARK: - Variables
var arrImagesSmall : [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profileDetailsSmall"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "gigParameterSmall"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pricingSmall"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "availabilitySmall")]
var arrImagesBig : [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profileDetailsBig"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "gigParamertersBig"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pricingBig"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "availabilitySmall")]
let lastPageNum = 4
var presentPageNum: Int = 0 {
    didSet{

        self.lblPageNum?.text = self.presentPageNum.toString
        switch self.presentPageNum {
        case 1:
            self.imgViewLeft?.image = nil
            self.viewLeftMost?.isHidden = true
            self.viewLeftCenter?.isHidden = true
            self.imgViewCenter?.image = self.arrImagesBig[self.presentPageNum - 1]
            self.imgViewRight?.image = self.arrImagesSmall[self.presentPageNum]
        case self.lastPageNum:
            self.imgViewRight?.image = nil
            self.viewRightMost?.isHidden = true
            self.viewRightCenter?.isHidden = true
            self.imgViewLeft?.image = self.arrImagesSmall[self.presentPageNum - 2]
            self.imgViewCenter?.image = self.arrImagesBig[self.presentPageNum - 1]
        default:
                self.viewLeftMost?.isHidden = false
                self.viewLeftCenter?.isHidden = false
                self.viewRightMost?.isHidden = false
                self.viewRightCenter?.isHidden = false
                self.imgViewLeft?.image = self.arrImagesSmall[self.presentPageNum - 2]
                self.imgViewCenter?.image = self.arrImagesBig[self.presentPageNum - 1]
                self.imgViewRight?.image = self.arrImagesSmall[self.presentPageNum]
        }

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    presentPageNum = presentPageNum + 1
}

//MARK: ----- ACTION METHODS
@IBAction func nextPage(_ sender: Any){
    if presentPageNum != lastPageNum {
        presentPageNum = presentPageNum + 1
    }
}
```

}

Now I want to animate the transition so that it gives a sliding effect. I have tried some basic animation code but no luck. Open for suggestions to implement it in some other or better way.

***EDIT: 1***
In my default case i added following code for animation:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                    self.imgViewRight?.center = (self.imgViewCenter?.center)!
                    self.imgViewRight?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
                }, completion: nil)
```

This workes fine but now the issue I am facing is, should I add new imageview for the right-hand side image every time as imgViewRight has moved to center.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be hard to do this as an animation. "I have tried some basic animation code but no luck." That's not helpful. Edit your question to show the code you've tried, and explain how it fails to meet your needs.

Comment: In general, you should not swap images, but rather shift your image over. Then you could just wrap the code that shifts the position of the image in a call to `UIImage.animate()` (There are several flavors of UIView animation calls. See the docs for more info.)

Comment: should I animate uiimageview or uimage?

Comment: You really animate an image. Create an image view using an image that is wider than the visible section. Place it such that it extends beyond the edge of its parent view. Then create animations that shift it over by the desired amounts.

Comment: @DuncanC as you said I added animation code, check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I add new imageview for the right-hand side image every time as imgViewRight has moved to center

Throw away your existing code. Do not show or hide or add or remove anything. Just line up all four image views and leave them there, and animate them all together each time. If you put them into a superview the animation is trivial. Slide the superview sideways while changing the scale transforms of two of the image views, the one that was in the center and the one that will be in the center.

It took me about five minutes to set this up:

[image]

Here's the actual animation part, for the Next button:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.slider.frame.origin.x -= self.pageWidth
    self.imageViews[self.currentPage].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.currentPage += 1
    self.imageViews[self.currentPage].transform = .identity
}
```

Comment: Basically it’s an elementary carousel. Google that term.

Comment: Added screencast to show strategy in action. I didn't bother to replicate all the details of your original but that's just chrome you can add easily.

Comment: I missed the fact that the selected icon gets bigger, and thought sliding a single static image view was going to be enough. Good catch. As you say, this is pretty trivial. Did you write code to create your animation, or did you have a sample on hand already

Comment: @DuncanC I just threw something together quickly from scratch; took about five minutes once I had created the images. The Prev and Next buttons are just an animation block with three lines of code: slide the container view and change the transforms of the two image views.

Comment: Yup. Trivial. If you're feeling kind you might want to post the code.

Comment: Well, the OP has the idea already. I've posted the animation part of the code for what it's worth.